# Selecting correct installation disk

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, install

I'm trying to install a piece of software (specifically JMP Pro 16) onto my Macbook Air running OS Monterey. When I get to the "Destination Select" screen of the install process, it gives me two choices of "Macintosh HD" disks (see below).
[image: Screenshot of JMP Pro 16 installer's "Select Destination" screen.]

The first Macintosh HD disk, showing 16.08 GB available is shown as **disk1s5s1**, and the second Macintosh HD disk, showing 14 GB available is shown as **disk1s5**. Looking at my DiskUtility, it seems the disk1s5s1 might either be the APFS Volume Group, or the APFS Startup Snapshot.

[image: Screenshot of DiskUtility sidebar.]

Which disk should I use as an installation destination? Does it matter which one I choose?